# Send ObservableCollection<object> info to another view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, chat, messaging

I want to implement somekind of messaging communciation (I know how to use messaging of MVVM.Light) but I think my case is trickier, because I'm using the CommandParameter to change ViewModel, I can't add the command I want :x to the code to become more clear.
[image]

**XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}" Height="314" BorderThickness="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemFriends}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="Resources\Images\ic_status.png" Height="24" Width="18"/>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding name}"/>                                
                        <StackPanel x:Name="RemoveItems" Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastLocation}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding timestamp}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="AdditionItems" Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=loc.area}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=loc.building}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=loc.floor}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=loc.room}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Button Style="{DynamicResource FlatButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectViewCommand, ElementName=GeneralWindowView}"  CommandParameter="ChatViewModel" x:Name="button1" Content="Chat" Margin="10">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Image Source="Resources\Images\chat_image.png"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="AdditionItems" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="RemoveItems" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

So I am in the FriendsViewModel (is a child of GeneralViewModel) and I want to send information to the ChatViewModel (also a child of GeneralViewModel). The thing is where can I fire the command ? Because I'm using the Command Parameter, I can't implement other command :x and use messenger.

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT: AViewModel**

```
public abstract class AViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //public WindowService ws;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand<string> SelectViewCommand { get; set; }

    public AViewModel()
    {
        //ws = new WindowService();
        SelectViewCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(OnSelectViewCommand);
    }

    private static ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> _ViewModels;
    public static ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> ViewModels
    {
        get { return _ViewModels; }
        set { _ViewModels = value; }
    }

    public void AddViewModel(ViewModelBase viewmodel)
    {
        if (ViewModels == null)
            ViewModels = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();

        var currentVNs = (from vms in ViewModels where vms.InternalName == viewmodel.InternalName select vms).FirstOrDefault();
        if (currentVNs == null)
            ViewModels.Add(viewmodel);
    }

    public ViewModelBase GetViewModel(string viewmodel)
    {
        return ViewModels.FirstOrDefault(item => item.InternalName == viewmodel);
    }
    public ViewModelBase GetViewModelLogin(string viewmodel,object bla)
    {
        return ViewModels.FirstOrDefault(item => item.InternalName == viewmodel);
    }

    private void OnSelectViewCommand(string obj)
    {
        switch (obj)
        {
            case "ExitCommand":
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
                break;
            default:
                this.Current_ViewModel = this.GetViewModel(obj);
                break;
        }
    }

    private ViewModelBase _Current_ViewModel;
    private IMessenger _messengerInstance;

    public ViewModelBase Current_ViewModel
    {
        get { return _Current_ViewModel; }
        set { _Current_ViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("Current_ViewModel"); }
    }
    protected IMessenger MessengerInstance
    {
        get
        {
            return this._messengerInstance ?? Messenger.Default;
        }
        set
        {
            this._messengerInstance = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just notify the other ViewModel inside the Action of the SelectViewCommand?

Comment: See edited question. Basically is the interface, I'm using Rachel MVVM example as base :)

Answer (score 0):

If you remember in my last demo I was raising an 'Event' in the setter of property 'Current_ViewModel' in AviewModel that gets fired every time you navigate to a different View. Well, after thinking about it I had the idea that the Event can also send an object [to the new ViewModel\View] also....

you need to use the 'CommandParameter' class tho...

```
public enum Command
{
    None,
    LogIn,
    LogOut,
    Recovery,
    Register,
    Exit
}

public class CommandParameter
{
    public dynamic Obj { get; set; }

    public Command Command { get; set; }

    public string Link_1 { get; set; }

    public string Link_2 { get; set; }
}
```

example usage...

```
this.LogInCommandParameter = new CommandParameter() { Obj = this.CurrentUser, Command = Command.LogIn, Link_1 = "Main_ViewModel", Link_2 = "LogOnError_ViewModel" };
```

in the above code

```
 Obj = the object you want to send onto you next View
 Command = is a 'hint' that you can Switch on in your Buttons bound Command
 Link_1 &  Link_2 are the Views that you want to Navigate too....
```

there is a lot more to it than that so I have attached another demo here http://www.mediafire.com/download/5ttjhuiuxex7eo1/Navigation1_25-05.rar (file size is quite big now because the Demo uses EF and there is a web service too.... should all work from VS IDE tho)

you'll see in AviewModel

```
    private ViewModelBase _Current_ViewModel;
    public ViewModelBase Current_ViewModel
    {
        get { return _Current_ViewModel; }
        set {
            if (Current_ViewModel != null)
                Current_ViewModel.RaiseDeActivate(SendObject);
            _Current_ViewModel = value;
            if (Current_ViewModel != null)
                Current_ViewModel.RaiseActivate(SendObject);
            OnPropertyChanged("Current_ViewModel"); }
    }
```

I am now raising two events (DeActivate and Activate) and also note that I am sending a param called SendObject (this is your Obj in CommandParameter)...

in the ViewModel you simply subscribe to the Events like so....

```
    // in the constructor....
    this.Activate += Main_ViewModel_Activate;
    this.DeActivate += Main_ViewModel_DeActivate;

    private void Main_ViewModel_DeActivate(object sender, ActivateArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Main_ViewModel_Activate(object sender, ActivateArgs e)
    {
        // e.Data will be the SendObject from AviewModel
    }
```

Have a look\step though at the Demo code... you'll see that (after creating a new user to log on with) once you log on with a valid UserName\Password, that 'User' (the entire 'User' Object) is passed FROM LogOn_ViewModel TO  Main_ViewModel VIA the OnWindowCommand in Base_ViewModel... the UserName (that you used to log on with in LogOn_View) is then displayed on the Main_View.

Comment: do you think there is any other solution? Because I think that doing that I have to make alterations in a lot of code. If you see my XAML code I've already managed to change the viewmodels correctly and I've knowledge of how to send messages through MVVM Light, the thing here is that I want to use the same button to do both > Send message + change view model

Comment: But that's the thing... to do both and Send message + change viewmodel you need to provide more information in the CommandParameter (not just the string name of the next ViewModel). That's were the CommandParameter Class comes into play, You create a CommandParameter for each button and provide information about VMs to navigate to and objects to forward on to that VM....

Comment: in the example you'll notice that 'Obj' contains the User currently logged on,  'Link_1' is the new VM to navigate to and 'Link_2' is the VM to display if there is an error.... I don't see how your gonna do all that by simply sending a string using the XAML CommandParameter....

Comment: Can MVVM Light Send message + change view model at the same time? If so, why don't you us that? I know there are two events Activate and Deactivate raised when switching Views, personally I find third party frameworks unnecessary add complexity that you can achieve yourself much easier....

Comment: Can MVVM Light Send message + change view model at the same time? I don't truly know, but I don't think so. I do not need this behavior for the login, I'm using a thing called singleton that permits that I have that information throughout the app, but I create a new window ... MainWindow(LoginChildView) > newWindow(has access to the singleton). But even singletons this time I don't see how can I use them...

Comment: Even so I still have to find a way to transmit the information of the SelectedItemFriends since the button is inside the ListView in every row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112963/discussion-between-antoine-and-monty).